# Is there a way to specify a cutoff level for printing logs to the output in python?

Tags: python, logging

Is there a way to specify a *cutoff level* for printing logs in python when using the `logging` module? E.g. Logs of level `INFO` won't be printed to stdout if this *cutoff level* is set to `WARNING`. I was thinking there would be something like an environment variable that would achieve that, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Like setting the log level? https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel

Comment: Yeah. Was hoping for predefined args on the commandline to set that.

Comment: If you're willing to modify the code, you could add an environment variable to control it, like in [this tutorial](https://powerfulpython.com/blog/nifty-python-logging-trick/).